# How to check Docker API for misconfigured Docker API port

Tags: docker

On a VM I've caught a Malware Minor called *Kinsing* which is well described here: https://sysdig.com/blog/zoom-into-kinsing-kdevtmpfsi/

While I could clean the VM from infection the interesting question is how the attacker could ingest the malware.

**Different Resources agree on these entry points:**

- A Unsecured Redis image

  B Apache Solar

  C Outdated PHP Module

  D misconfigured Docker API port

> The attack pattern starts with the attackers identifying a misconfigured Docker API port that has been left open to the public internet. (https://blog.aquasec.com/threat-alert-kinsing-malware-container-vulnerability)

While I do not use A-C my question is if my check for a vulnerable Docker Api Port is correct. I'm following this [guide](https://www.intezer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Fixing-a-Common-Yet-Deadly-Mistake-Misconfigured-Docker-API-Ports.pdf)

From Outside I do an NMAP with the following result:

```
sudo nmap -sTV -p 2376 SERVER_IP
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-22 20:07 CET
Nmap scan report for SERVER_IP
Host is up (0.037s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE VERSION
2376/tcp filtered docker
```

At the server I do check:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp 

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1137/smbd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      962/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1072/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6556            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      954/xinetd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1137/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1137/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1456/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      962/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1470/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1072/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1392/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1137/smbd
```

As I do not see Dockerd listening on port 2375 or 2376 I do assume my Docker Ports are secure.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, from your netstat it show your docker run a webserver (80 & 443) the malware can Entering your server is probably due to an error setting the permissions and ownership of the running container or any running web application that is vulnerable, since the default access on the container is root then the attacker can exploit from it.

Back to the topic, you can see the docker API from

`systemctl status docker -l`

If the docker API exposed and active you will see the PID like :

```
 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --some-flag-or-option:2375
```